# Скажите пожалуйста, что я делаю не так?

Tags: python, python-3.x, числа-фибоначчи

Каждый следующий элемент ряда Фибоначчи получается при сложении двух предыдущих. Начиная с 1 и 2, первые 10 элементов будут:

1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, ...

Найдите сумму всех четных элементов ряда Фибоначчи, которые не превышают четыре миллиона.

```
fib1 = 2
fib2 = 3
s = 0
n = int(input('Введите номер элемента последовательности'))

i = 0
if (fib1 <= 4000000 ) and (fib2 <= 4000000):
    while i < n - 2: # n-2 потому что два числа фиббоначи уже имеют значения
      if fib1 % 2 == 0:
          s = s + fib1
      elif fib2 % 2 == 0:
          s = s + fib2
        fib_sum = fib2 + fib1
        fib1 = fib2
        fib2 = fib_sum
        i += 1
print (s)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы добавляете каждое четное число (кроме двух) два раза.

Что такое `n`?

Проверять на `4 000 000` надо в цикле.

---

Это делается проще, если заметить, что каждое третье число - четное.

```
a = 0
b = 1
c = 2
sum = 0
while c <= 4000000:
    sum = sum + c
    a = b + c
    b = c + a
    c = a + b
print(sum)
```